# Traefik Ingress for External Service Troubleshooting

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

Need a little assistance please.

I'm trying to get Traefik to act as an ingress for everything in my lab, both K8s hosted pods/services and external services hosted on a Docker host.

I have created an external service object for the service I want to reach:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: ha.local.lan
  ports:
   - name: http
     port : 49153
     targetPort: 49153
```

then, I have created an IngressRoute object for that service:

```
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami
  #namespace: default
spec:
#  tls: {}
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`whoami.local.lan`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      services:
    # The service name and port must match the Service
    # specified in the deploy file
      - name: whoami
        port: 49153
```

The router appears in Traefik just fine, but the routing of the traffic to port 49153 doesn't seem to work. I can reach the dns name, but I still have to add the port to my URL to reach the site.

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Let me get that straight: You are trying to use your ingress controller for a service that is not on your kubernetes cluster. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. ExternalService.

Comment: Your entrypoint for the route is web — 80 by default. When you add the port, it is likely you bypass your ingresscontroller altogether. You sure port 49153 on the target machine is accessible from your k8s?